# How to set up android TCP client?

Tags: android, client

I'm trying to set up a client in android. I searched the internet but couldn't find a normal client that can send and receive messages. Most of them use AsyncTask in  a wrong way. AsyncTask is meant for short  actions(few seconds top) but most examples use this for along actions.  Can someone help me?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples and tutorials for this. Unless you have a very special and specific need many of these references can be found with a simple Internet search. Good Luck!

Comment: but most of them use AsyncTask in  a wrong way. AsyncTask is meant for short  actions but most examples use this for along time.

Comment: Then just use a new `Thread` and perhaps a `Handler` object. Have a google!